# Use order item meta data via a custom action button in Woocommerce admin orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

So I have created a custom action button in my woocommerce order list, but I want the button to link to a page where I will print out information attached to that order. Now to do so I would like to carry data from the order to the page where I am going to print the information.

So I have created my custom button in the woocommerce order list with this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions_end', 'add_content_to_wcactions_column' );
function add_content_to_wcactions_column() {

    // create some tooltip text to show on hover
    $tooltip = __('Print details', 'textdomain');

    // create a button label
    $label = __('P1', 'textdomain');

    $printurl = wc_get_order_item_meta($post_id, 'street-name', true);

    echo '<a class="button tips custom-class" href="/order-info/?orderid='.$printurl.'" data-tip="'.$tooltip.'" target="_blank">'.$label.'</a>';
}
```

The button links to the print page which should carry the orders 'street-name' meta, but the meta doesnt show, it just appears blank in the url.

Heres what my order item information looks like:

[image]

I should say im using the [WooCommerce Custom Product Addons](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-custom-product-addons/) plugin if that helps.

Comment: I would just create a password protected page, with a custom page template, that prints out the order data by order id

Comment: @ShirGans do you have a example of that? I cannot find the right code to display woocommerce data by id anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes and missing things in your code, like:

- `$order` argument is missing from the hooked function
- `$post_id` is not defined.
- You need to get first the correct **Item ID** to use `wc_get_order_item_meta()` function

**Reminder:** An order can have many items (products).

In the following code we will get the first order Item *(assuming that `street-name` is the correct `meta_key` to get the custom order item meta data value)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions_end', 'admin_order_actions_custom_button' );
function admin_order_actions_custom_button( $order ) {

    // create some tooltip text to show on hover
    $tooltip = __('Print details', 'textdomain');

    // create a button label
    $label = __('P1', 'textdomain');

    // get order line items
    $order_items = $order->get_items();

    // get the first item
    $first_item  = reset( $order_items );

    // get 'street-name' order item custom meta data
    $print_url   = $first_item->get_meta('street-name'); // or: wc_get_order_item_meta($first_item->get_id(), 'street-name', true);

    echo '<a class="button tips custom-class" href="/order-info/?orderid='.$print_url.'" data-tip="'.$tooltip.'" target="_blank">'.$label.'</a>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: I still get nothing when using this. Im using this plugin to create the data https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-custom-product-addons/ maybe this is creating the data differently?

Comment: @brandbei37 You need to check in the database on  `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table to find out which is the correct `meta_key`… Nobody can guess that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you meant that street-name is the meta key for the order or the item, so I covered both cases in the following code, you can delete what's not relevant for you.

Here is an example of page template that will get order ID in the querystring, and will display some information.

To make this happen, you need to create a php file in your theme directory, you can call it "template-order-info.php" and paste this content into it.

Then, go to your admin and create a new page and assign the page template from the select box to be "Order Info" (the new file).

Then view the file, and add the following query string: /?order=#### (replace with the order ID). so for example: www.mysite.com/orderinfo/?order=1001

```
    <?php
/* Template Name: Order Info */

$order_id = $_GET['order'];

# Some basic filtering for wrong order ID passed
if (!is_numeric($order_id)) wp_die('Invalid Order ID');

$order = new WC_Order($order_id);

if (!$order) wp_die('Invalid Order ID');

get_header();
    ?>

<h2>Order #<?php echo $order->get_id(); ?> Information</h2>

<ul>
    <li>Full Name: <?php echo $order->get_billing_first_name().' '.$order->get_billing_last_name(); ?> </li>
    <li>Street Name: <?php echo $order->get_meta('street-name'); ?></li>
    <li>Billing Address: <?php echo $order->get_billing_address_1(); ?></li>
    <li>Billing Address 2: <?php echo $order->get_billing_address_2(); ?></li>
    <li>
        <h3>Order Items:</h3>
        <ol>
            <?php foreach ($order->get_items() as $item){ 
                ?>
                <li><strong><?php echo $item->get_name(); ?></strong> - Street Name: <?php echo $item->get_meta('street-name');?></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>


    <?php
get_footer();
```